# Access denied for user on cPanel

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to connect to the database but nothing is working, Access denied for user 'taraegwg_taranova'@'server289-2.web-hosting.com' (using password: YES).

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('taranovaauctions.com', 'taraegwg_taranova','w(uzytr4Nz@C','taraegwg_taranova_db');
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        exit('connection error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
?>
```

If I change it 'taranovaauctions.com' to this 'server289-2.web-hosting.com' nothing will change I already tried - error screenshot:
[image: error screenshot]

And when I go to phpMyAdmin through cPanel I have a completely different user for some reason - screenshot phpmyadmin user:
[image: screenshot phpmyadmin user]

I also checked the privileges of my user (taraegwg taranova) but it gave an error and the error says that the user from the second screenshot "cpses_tacqk1qvh2" @ "localhost" is denied access to the "mysql" database. - access denied:
[image: access denied]

Сhecking for the privileges of this user - "cpses_tacqk1qvh2" @ "localhost" showed full access to this user - taraegwg taranova) - all privileges:
[image: all privileges]

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the MySQL server is on 'taranovaauctions.com'?  Most of the time the MySQL server is located at a different address.  Also, the user must exist in that server also.  Ask your host provider.

Comment: @CharlesEF, i chage host to "localhost" and connected to the database, but now it just throws me a 500 error. I register, the user is added to the database, but nothing is added to the session and the redirect does not occur, just a 500 error. I developed on open Server and everything worked fine there

Comment: A 500 is a general error message from the server.  You should be able to check the server error logs to find out more information.  Also, maybe you can check the 'Network' tab in your browsers developer tools.  I thought you were having trouble on the internet (reference to cPanel).  Anyway, the user you are trying to log in as must exist on the localhost database server.

Comment: Also, if the user does exist then they need permission for the database itself.